# Возможные утечки памяти в реализации класса содержащего шаблонный массив и его размер

Tags: c++, c++11, утечка-памяти

Добрый день. Есть следующий класс с реализацией правила 3, точнее 4:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
class Array
{
public:

    //constructor
  Array(const size_t size = 0)
    : m_size(size)
    , m_array(m_size ? new T[m_size]() : nullptr)
  {}


  //destructor
  ~Array()
    {
        delete[] m_array;
    }


  friend void swap(Array& first, Array& second)
  {
      using std::swap;
      swap(first.m_size, second.m_size);
      swap(first.m_array, second.m_array);
  }


  size_t size() const
  {
      return m_size;
  }


  T& operator [](const size_t index)
  {
      assert(index < m_size);
      return m_array[index];
  }


  //move-construct
  Array(Array&& other)
          : Array()
      {
          swap(*this, other);
      }


  //copy-constructor
      Array(const Array& other)
          : m_size(other.m_size),
            m_array(m_size ? new T[m_size] : nullptr)
      {
          std::copy(other.m_array, other.m_array + m_size, m_array);
      }

  //copy-assignment
  Array& operator=(Array other)
  {
      swap(*this, other);
      return *this;
  }


private:

  size_t m_size;
  T* m_array;
};
```

По заданию необходимо было добавить реализацию конструктора копирования, конструктора перемещения, оператора присваивания, что и было сделано, при этом "Разработанный класс должен давать строгую гарантию безопасности исключений", коему правилу вроде удовлетворяет. Но при отправке на проверку получаю сообщение: "В реализации массива возможна утечка памяти". Помогите локализовать.

Comment: код отформатируйте, в таком виде читать невозможно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор копирования выполняет копирование элементов из другого массива. Если копирующий оператор присваивания класса `T` кинет исключение, то память, выделенная под этот массив утечет (и уже созданные элементы массива не будет разрушены, потенциально создавая еще больше утечек).

Копирующий оператор присваивания должен принимать на вход `Array const &`, а перемещающий `Array &&`, а у вас ни рыба, ни мясо (хотя может это и соответствует заданию).

Comment: А можете пояснить как устранит эту утечку?

Comment: @ProstoNekitos Основная проблема с copy-and-swap - оверхед от одновременного существования 3 объектов при копировании. Утечку легко устранить используя вместо сырого указателя умный указатель `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Это задание с онлайн-платформы Stepik, там не получится их использовать, по-крайней мере, в данном задании

Comment: @ProstoNekitos Почему это не получиться? Стандартная библиотека там же есть.

Comment: Не получится ввиду организации задания, всё что мне доступно - лишь добавление своих методов (копирования, присвоения, перемещения)  в готовый класс

Comment: @ProstoNekitos Ну тогда только ловить исключения, самостоятельно удалять выделенную память, и кидать исключения дальше.

Comment: Копирующий оператор присваивания как раз таки реализован совершенно правильно. Именно таким способом - передача по значению - мы эффективно покрываем и копирование, и перемещение. Отдельные версии могут получиться чуть-чуть эффективнее, но в большинстве случае это не нужно.